# Using function to find expression

Tags: calculus

Consider the function  $f(x) = \frac{2}{x-1}$. It says to find an expression for $f(x+h)$.

I think the answer is $f(x+h)= -2/(x+h)$ I have the right answer, but it's not accepting it.

Any help?

Comment: It is not the right answer. Why is the denominator $-(x+h)$?

Comment: Everywhere that you see $x$, write $x+h$. In the case $\frac{2}{x-1}$, we see $x$ in only one place, replacement by $x+h$ is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=\frac2{(x)-1}$

$\displaystyle f(x+h)=\frac2{(x+h)-1}$

The idea is to replace all occurrences of $x$ with $x+h$

Comment: yeah i know that, so you dont have to factor the bottom with -1?

Comment: @jayson, not sure what is meant by factor here. The idea is leave the constants as is

Comment: awesome gotcha! thanks guys!