# Consider the funcition and find an expression

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{2}{x-1}$ and find an expression for $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and simplify where he cannot be equal to $0$.

Comment: You were almost there, just write $ signs around the math expressions next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

$$f(x) = \frac 2{x - 1}$$

$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{\dfrac{2}{(x + h) - 1} - \dfrac {2}{x - 1}}{h}$$

Multipy numerator and denominator by $(x + h - 1)(x - 1)$

$$\begin {align}\frac{\dfrac{2}{(x + h) - 1} - \dfrac {2}{x - 1}}{h} \cdot \frac{ \dfrac{(x + h - 1)(x - 1)}{1}}{(x + h - 1)(x - 1)} & = \frac{2(x - 1) - 2(x + h - 1)}{h(x+h - 1)(x - 1)}\\ \\ & = \dfrac{-2\cancel{h}}{\cancel{h}(x+h + 1)(x-1)}\end{align}$$

After canceling the common factor, you're done.

Comment: Needs something to go with the green arrow, what could it be? =1

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494574/using-function-to-find-expression). $$f(x+h)=\frac2{x+h-1}$$

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\frac2{x+h-1}-\frac2{x-1}=\frac{2(x-1)-2(x+h-1)}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}$$
$$\implies f(x+h)-f(x)=-\frac{2h}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}$$

So, if $h\ne0,$ $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=-\frac2{(x+h-1)(x-1)}$$

Additionally, do you remember $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=f'(x)\text{ and }h\to0\implies h\ne0$$